# List navigation visibility on Internet explorer

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, navigation, wordpress-theming

My navigation hover list appears fine on Chrome and Firefox but not internet explorer. You can find my **[website here](http://goo.gl/aLm7NM)**.

When you hover over "services" on IE, the background of the hover segment is 100% transparent and the words do not display until the mouse cursor moves further down the list. When I right click to go to inspect element the hover list appears fine.

Please visit the site on Chrome or firefox to see what it should look like.

Is there a code to fix this for IE?

```
#header-s6.header-mega #navigation .sub-menu{
                position: absolute;
                display: none;
                width:200px;
                padding:0;
                top: 87px;
                left: 15px;
                background: #999999;
                border:none;
                border-top:3px solid #555555;
                z-index: 20000;
                -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
                        border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px; 
                -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
                   -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
                        box-shadow:1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            }

            #header-s6.header-mega #navigation .sub-menu li{
                float: none;
                border: none;
                margin: 0px 10px;
                padding: 0;
                height: auto;
                position: relative;
             }

            #header-s6.header-mega #navigation .sub-menu li a{
                height: auto;
                line-height: 1;
                display: block !important;
                text-align: left;
                color: #dedede;
                text-transform: none;
                padding:10px 6px;
                margin:0;
                border: none;
                font-weight: normal;
                border-bottom:1px solid #a5a5a5;
            }

            #header-s6.header-mega #navigation .sub-menu li:last-child a { border: none; }

            #header-s6.header-mega #navigation .sub-menu li:hover{
                border: none;
                font-weight: inherit;
            }

            #header-s6.header-mega #navigation .sub-menu li a:hover{
                color: #ffffff;
                border-bottom:1px solid #a5a5a5;
                font-weight: inherit;
            }

            #header-s6.header-mega #navigation .sub-menu li.current-menu-item > a,
            #header-s6.header-mega #navigation .sub-menu li.current-menu-item > a:hover,
            #header-s6.header-mega #navigation .sub-menu li.current-page-ancestor > a,
            #header-s6.header-mega #navigation .sub-menu li.current-page-ancestor > a:hover,
            #header-s6.header-mega #navigation .sub-menu li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
            #header-s6.header-mega #navigation .sub-menu li.current-menu-ancestor > a:hover,
            #header-s6.header-mega #navigation .sub-menu li.current-menu-parent > a,
            #header-s6.header-mega #navigation .sub-menu li.current-menu-parent > a:hover,
            #header-s6.header-mega #navigation .sub-menu li.current_page_ancestor > a,
            #header-s6.header-mega #navigation .sub-menu li.current_page_ancestor > a:hover { color: #ffffff; }

        /* 2nd Level */

            #header-s6.header-mega #navigation .sub-menu ul{
                position: absolute;
                left: 200px;
                margin: 0 0 0 -8px;
                top: 0;
                border: none;
                -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
                        border-radius: 2px;
            }

            #header-s6.header-mega #navigation .sub-menu ul li a{
                width: auto;
                display: block;
                text-align: left;
                color: #dedede;
                text-transform: none;
                padding:10px 6px;
                margin:0;
                border: none;
                border-bottom:1px solid #a5a5a5 !important;
            }

            #header-s6.header-mega #navigation ul li ul li.current-menu-item > a { color: #ee7171; }

            /* mega */

                #header-s6.header-mega #navigation > ul > li.mega{
                    position: inherit !important;  
                    margin: 0;
                    z-index: 9000;
                }

                #header-s6.header-mega #navigation > ul > li.mega > ul.sub-menu{ 
                    width: 940px;    
                    left: 0px;
                    right: 0px;
                    padding: 12px 0px 16px 0;
                    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
                    background-color: #999999;
                    border-top:3px solid #555555;
                }

                #header-s6.header-mega #navigation > ul > li.mega > ul > li{
                    float: left !important;
                    padding: 0px 20px;
                    width: 25%;
                    margin: 0 0;
                }

                #header-s6.header-mega #navigation > ul > li.mega > ul > li:last-child{
                    border-right: none !important;
                }

                #header-s6.header-mega #navigation ul > li.mega.columns-3 > ul > li { width: 33.33%; }
                #header-s6.header-mega #navigation ul > li.mega.columns-4 > ul > li { width: 25%; }
                #header-s6.header-mega #navigation ul > li.mega.columns-5 > ul > li { width: 20%; }
                #header-s6.header-mega #navigation ul > li.mega.columns-6 > ul > li { width: 16.66%; }

                #header-s6.header-mega #navigation > ul > li.mega > ul > li ul{
                    display: block !important;
                    top: 0px !important;
                    width: 100%;
                    opacity: 1 !important;
                    left: 0px !important;
                    position: relative !important;
                    border: none;
                    -webkit-border-radius: none;
                            border-radius: none; 
                    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
                       -moz-box-shadow: none;
                            box-shadow: none;
                }

                #header-s6.header-mega #navigation > ul > li.mega > ul > li{ border-right: 1px solid #a5a5a5 !important; }

                #header-s6.header-mega #navigation > ul > li.mega ul li a{
                    border-bottom: none!important;
                    padding: 8px 10px;
                    /*-webkit-transition: all 0.05s ease-in;
                    -moz-transition: all 0.05s ease-in;
                     -ms-transition: all 0.05s ease-in;
                      -o-transition: all 0.05s ease-in;
                         transition: all 0.05s ease-in;*/
                    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
                            border-radius: 2px; 
                }

                #header-s6.header-mega #navigation > ul > li.mega > ul > li > a,
                #header-s6.header-mega #navigation > ul > li.mega > ul > li > a:hover{
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    margin-bottom: 5px;
                    font-weight: 600 !important;
                    color:#444444 !important;
                    cursor: default;
                }

                #header-s6.header-mega #navigation > ul > li.mega > ul ul li a:hover, 
                #header-s6.header-mega #navigation > ul > li.mega > ul ul li.current-menu-item a{
                    color: #ffffff;
                    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) !important;
                    border: none !important;
                }

                #header-s6.header-mega #navigation > ul > li.mega > ul > li > a:hover, 
                #header-s6.header-mega #navigation > ul > li.mega > ul > li.sfHover > a { background-color: transparent !important; }

                #header-s6.header-mega #navigation ul li.mega ul li ul li{
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                }

                #header-s6 #navigation #nav .sub-menu li ul{
                    left: 0;
                    margin-left: 15px;
}`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include a self-contained example of your problem here. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: RNDM, Could you post your navigation html, css, and js?

Comment: @mooseman thanks for the comment. However I believe in education before degradation...people tend to learn better that way :-)

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: newest version: 11.0.9600